# Альтернатива JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc

Имеется скрипт который берет значение (номер строки) из hidden поля в динамически генерируемой таблице asp.net файла, подставляет его в запрос и отправляет в другой документ.

Возможно ли сделать подобное без использования JavaScript?

Как в asp.net можно получить Id из динамически сгенерированной таблицы и передать его в контроллер?

Comment: asp это серверная сторона вопроса, а клиент получает html, css, javascript ... etc.
Без JS тут не обойтись

Comment: Какими еще способами можно воплотить подобное? "только" JavaScript?

Comment: @Dobermann в гугл, ей богу достали подобного рода вопросы -_-

Comment: AlexWindHope а в чем проблема то? не нравится вопрос, проходи мимо..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, существуют технологии, позволяющие писать на строго типизированных языках клиентский код, который при рендеринге преобразуется в JavaScript. Как они точно называются, не помню.

Comment: И в чем выгода?

Comment: Примером является Google GWT: пишем на Java, компилируем в JavaScript. Выгода (которая проявляется далеко не всегда) в упрощении разработки сложных интерфейсов, а также повышение переносимости кода.

Comment: Туда же FSharp.WebTools (http://fswebtools.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Google Dart как я понимаю тоже выпустили как "замену" javascript?